# Upload App to Azure Ad without registering new app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

is it possible to upload an app (manifest) to azure ad with a certain id specified in manifest file? Until now I added my apps via app registration. That works fine, but in this step appId is generated and cannot be changed.

Background information:
I want to develop an app that can be used in different tenants and uses protected apis to access data in teams (by graph api). To use this kind of api I have to register my app with microsoft. So appId is fix.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify the appId, it is always generated.
It sounds like you might want a multi-tenant app?
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant.

This allows the same app registration to be replicated to any Azure AD tenant.
It is what SaaS applications typically use for example.

Comment: Hm, replication and SaaS sounds not like the thing I want :(
Nevertheless I will have a look to provided documentation.